# After deleting user 0's locksettings.db, user 10 (Island work profile) failed to decrypt in TWRP

Tags: lock-screens, twrp, android-11, pattern-lock, work-profiles

My Pixel 5 running Android 11, encountered a frozen screen when attempting to set the screen lock to none.

[image]

After the system auto reboots, the device prompts for unlocking the screen pattern. Even entering the correct pattern, the work profile consistently prompts for unlocking,

[image]

The issue seems from using One Lock to secure the device but not removing the screen lock pattern successfully.

> [image]

Following a [guide](https://xdaforums.com/t/remove-bypass-lockscreen-with-recovery.3530008/) to delete locksetting files allowed successful access to the device. However, the **work profile prevents the opening of apps.**

Rebooting to TWRP (3.7.0_11-0) seems user 10's data is encrypted.
Also following [How to decrypt Island / Work profile and Parallel Apps user in TWRP?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/231415/how-to-decrypt-island-work-profile-and-parallel-apps-user-in-twrp), the same, does not solve the issue.

**Any solution to decrypt the work profile data without format?**

**Edit:**
According to the [using-adb-to-change-the-screen-lock](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/51180/using-adb-to-change-the-screen-lock)
I also attempted to remove the screen lock using ADB.

```
adb shell
locksettings clear --old MY_PASSWORD --user 0
locksettings clear --old MY_PASSWORD --user 10
locksettings verify --user 0
locksettings verify --user 10
```

both show **Lock credential verified successfully**
after rebooting to TWRP, user 10 still failed to decrypt

[image]

> [image]

Comment: with the "One Lock" feature you have probably successfully merged the locksettings of both profiles - then deleted locksettings

Comment: Thanks for your response, 

but in TWRP, I'm still unable to decrypt the data partition in user 10. 

Even when using "twrp decrypt my_pattern_password 10"
or "twrp decrypt default_password 10" in twrp terminal

it continues to show 'Failed to decrypt user 10.

Comment: It seems that after successfully locking my device, it fails to generate the password.key or pattern.key in data/system. However, the screen is still locked. Perhaps this is the reason why TWRP can't decrypt it, and the device is frozen and reboots.